# Is an electric field a transverse wave not in a vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

According to "Introduction to Plasma Physics and Controlled Fusion 3rd Edition", in discussing electromagnetic waves in a plasma, $\vec{E}$ is said to be a transverse wave. Is $\vec{E}$ a transverse wave even in a plasma? I only know the proof that $\vec{E}$ is a transverse wave "in a vacuum". By one of Maxwell equations and by assuming a plane wave solution, we easily get

$\frac{\rho}{\epsilon _0} = \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \vec{k} \cdot \vec{E}.$

$\vec{E}$ is not a transverse wave, is it?

(In the book, an equation $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ is used. So I have to know whether this equation is truly true.)

Comment: Given you are reading a book on plasma physics, have you tried just reading a little further? I suspect your question will be answered fairly soon.

Comment: @BySymmetry Thank you for your comment. I'm reviewing today's lesson, but the reason wasn't explained in the class and isn't found in the book. In my opinion, a plasma is always quasineutral so that $\rho$ is small and can be ignored. But I'm not confident.

Comment: @ynn Your assessment is incorrect. $\rho=0$ is typically true in equilibrium, but localized perturbations in the charge density are characteristic of many wave modes in plasmas (though not all).

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you. By "many wave modes", do you mean in a plasma $\vec{E}$ doesn't have to be a transverse wave? If so, why $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ is used in the book?

Comment: In the book, $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ is used to delete $\vec{\nabla} (i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{E})$. If the equation isn't true, I wonder if $\vec{\nabla} \rho$ can be ignored in a plasma.

Comment: Plasmas support many, *many* different types of wave.  By setting $\vec k \cdot \vec E=0$, you are restricting your attention to exclusively transverse waves.  In an unmagnetized plasma, this is characteristic of electromagnetic waves (though electrostatic waves exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\vec{E}$ is not a transverse wave, is it?

There is nothing wrong with transverse ($\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0$, e.g., [O-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_electron_wave#O_wave)) or longitudinal ($\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{E} = 0$, e.g., [ion acoustic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_acoustic_wave)) waves in a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)).

> Is $\vec{E}$ a transverse wave even in a plasma?

It can be, but again it is not required to be.  There are lots of waves with longitudinal oscillations of $\mathbf{E}$ that exist in a plasma and lots of work done measuring the electric fields associated with these modes (e.g., the following spacecraft measure electric and magnetic fields [Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIND_(spacecraft)), [THEMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/THEMIS), [MMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetospheric_Multiscale_Mission), etc.).